# What to do when a question is "attacked" by the comment brigade

Tags: discussion, questions, comments, answers

So there's a first time question, and yes surprisingly it's not that great.. what to do?

1. Vote to close,
2. Attach a snarky comment and get 10 million (exaggeration obviously)  up-votes
3. Sit back and edit the question (no praise) to try and **enable it to get the best answer possible** - which actually someone else (unless you're houdini!) will likely get the up-votes for by the time you've finished editing

see: [How to get a footer to stick to the end of my web page text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271875/how-to-get-a-footer-to-stick-to-the-end-of-my-web-page-text)

Q asked, Q downvoted 4 times (so far).. comments have all got huge up-votes, question has 1 close vote (that's why the comments I suppose no really good reason to close or it would be by now?) - Q has been edited **8** times (last by me) - I feel sorry for the question asker now, as I think it's lost...

yes I would now vote to close out of sympathy as people are likely only checking that question to add a snarky up-vote on a comment but really don't have a reason to close, nor can or will they answer.. and that's sad

so what to do if a "newb" q is under attack

Comment: The comments on that question aren't *that* bad. And I think the downvotes are being triggered, at least in part, by the OP's most-likely-in-bad-faith question editing. "Under attack" is over the top.

Comment: I agree comments are not that bad, but why just not vote to close or flag.. btw meta is scary! **Q is now closed** - under attack is not OTT in my opinion - as that is effectively what happened for 2 hours .. questions have been closed in 2 minutes before :) -  the question should have been closed or edited instead of slagged to the ground via comments.. why didn't people flag or vote to close before now? only one person attempted to answer

Comment: I would have removed _tell me which modification you made to get it to work fine_ from that post immediately, had I seen it before it was mobbed. The chances of getting non-snarky responses is near zero with a line that sounds so pretentious and demanding. (Even if it is clear that English is a second language.) _Any advice?_ would have been an easy fix...

Comment: @sarnold, so might I have but I was about 2 hours too late to party/question, and isn't hindsight wonderful! what I'm asking is how/why that didn't get flagged/voted to be closed/answered earlier than now - rather than a comment pat on the back thing taking place, why didn't someone edit out that rather obvious line? As far as I can tell those involved all had enough votes to do all four (answer, edit, vote to close or flag), - this is the opposite of comment wars in my opinion.. it's "let off steam at someone else's expense"

Comment: @clairesuzy: You might be vaguely interested by the newer comments in this question.

Comment: @thirtydot you mean this question or the on in the question ;)  - the other question should have stayed closed imho .. though I was looking forward to your reply, it best you didn't do their homework for them the "fix my code" attitude that was in original question is still there, definitely 'too localised' very uninteresting question -  especially if as you say it's actually fixed.

Comment: @clairesuzy: I meant in this question :) Yeah, I agree. I ended up looking at it again because I saw this Meta question, and it turned out to be a 2-liner JavaScript fix (where the alternative was *tons* of CSS changes..), so I figured I might as well try to post the quick solution for somebody having a hard time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I threw in the last vote to close because the question was of low quality and that link could go bad at any time which is of no use to man nor beast in the future. I also deleted a couple of the comments I thought were redundant/noise.

The remaining comments aren't that bad, they are telling the OP that he does have some serious issues with that site's HTML so I'll leave them there as food for thought for him/her whilst the question remains visible.

If there were serious problems with just downright rudeness then these comments should have been flagged.

Comment: Could you reopen that question? I *fully agree* with your reasons for closing the question (I voted to close it myself), but looking at it again now, I have a solution for the OP. I might as well post it.

Comment: @thirtydot - I've re-opened. Good luck :)

Comment: The OP managed to fix his site in the time between when I asked you to reopen his question, and now (when I remembered about this again). He did what I was going to suggest, which was to fix it via a couple of lines of JavaScript.

Comment: I voted too close too, even with a try at an edit - so I do agree with your answer - @thirtydot are you sure it's fixed and that OP is not looking for a CSS fix to take over from the JS fixed live "real page".. in any case I think this should likely be left alone and still be closed as 'too local' (can't re-vote though?) - now about [yesterday's one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295908/help-in-creating-a-slot-fruit-machine-style-cycling-div) .. another one same but different.. :)

Answer (score 11):

Flag for moderator attention. Usually the moderator will go in and clear out all the banter. Then the moderator will sometimes post a message telling everyone to stay on task. Bill the Lizard has done this before.

At any rate, the comments aren't that bad and should be taken as a teaching tool - even if it appears the OP is being browbeaten.

Comment: comments as a teaching tool is great, and it definitely works in some cases, I guess it's a fine line between dragging it out and making helpful points before closing or flagging  before OP get quite so browbeaten on their first attempt - +1, wish I could accept two answers

Comment: One valuable lesson that should have been learned from the days of USENET is to have _foldable and indented replies_.  "Moving things to chat" and "deleting banter" are terrible ideas, because I've seen moderators botch the value in such conversations by simply not having time to read everything through.  Banter tends to group (and hide by the nature of folding) out of the way.